# Using hibernate Envers, is there a way to delete entity from audit tables as well. Needed for GDPR compliance

Tags: hibernate-envers

Using hibernate Envers, is there a way to delete entity from audit tables as well. Needed for GDPR compliance Need a clean solution to comply with GDPR for completely deleting a record from all places.
Using envers 5.3.7